# Division algorithm for polynomials condition on field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I see the following theorem

> Let $F$ be a field. Suppose $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$ with $b(x)\neq 0$, then there exists $q(x),r(x)\in F$ such that $a(x)=b(x)q(x)+r(x)$, and either $r(x)=0$ or $\deg r(x)=\deg b(x)$.

How "relaxed" can $F$ be? For example, is the theorem still true if $F$ is an integral domain?

Comment: Yes and no. If the leading coefficient of $a(x)$ is a unit, then $F$ being an integral domain is sufficient. For general $a(x), b(x) \in F[x]$, no. You need this restriction on the leading coefficient of $a(x)$ for the division algorithm to still be possible.

Comment: Put another way, if $F$ is an integral domain, it is true in the field of fractions of $F.$ So,it is also true if the lead coefficient of $b$ divides the leading coefficient of $a.$ The bad news is you only get a single step this way.

Comment: Let $F$ be the integers, let $a(x)$ be $x$, let $b(x)$ be 2, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in comments:

> Yes and no. If the leading coefficient of $a(x)$ is a unit, then $F$ being an integral domain is sufficient. For general $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$, no. You need this restriction on the leading coefficient of $a(x)$ for the division algorithm to still be possible. –  AWertheim Jan 28 at 6:08

and

> Put another way, if $F$ is an integral domain, it is true in the field of fractions of $F$. So, it is also true if the lead coefficient of $b$ divides the leading coefficient of $a$. The bad news is you only get a single step this way. –  Will Jagy Jan 28 at 6:13